# how to display each data which is clicked in the jtable in netbeans in jtextfields

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection

i m doing a project and i need to display the data from the jtable to the jtextfields
i m using this code

`

```
private void MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                
int row =pm.getSelectedRow();
{
t1.setText(pm.getModel().getValueAt(row,1).toString());
t2.setText(pm.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
} 
// TODO add your handling code here:
    } `

 but in this case i am able to display only one data per click at the same textfields.
```

i want to display more than one data by clicking different data and display it in different textfields.

in this case when i click the data in the jtable i get the respective data in the textfield

***i want the new data clicked in new textfields***

pls help me and write some codes as i m new to netbeans

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to learn when the user has clicked on a particular row. You can query the `TableModel` and update the text fields in your implementation of `valueChanged()`.